# Passing values dynamically to an Ansible inventory - Python

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to `Ansible's Python API` in order to write a test API (in `Python`) which can take advantage of a playbook programmatically and add new nodes to a `Hadoop` cluster. As we know, at least node in the cluster has to be the `Namenode` and `JobTracker` (MRv1). For simplicity lets say the `JobTracker` and the `Namenode` are in the same node (`namenode_ip`).

Thus, in order to use `Ansible` to create a new node, and have it self registered with the `Namenode` I've created this following `Python` utility:

```
from ansible.playbook import PlayBook                                                                                                                
from ansible.inventory import Inventory                                                                                                              
from ansible.inventory import Group                                                                                                                  
from ansible.inventory import Host                                                                                                                   
from ansible import constants as C                                                                                                                   
from ansible import callbacks                                                                                                                        
from ansible import utils                                                                                                                            

import os                                                                                                                                            
import logging                                                                                                                                       
import config 

def run_playbook(ipaddress, namenode_ip, playbook, keyfile):                                                                                                                                                                     
      utils.VERBOSITY = 0                                                                                                                              
      playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)                                                                               
      stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()                                                                                                               
      runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(stats, verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)                                                                    

      host = Host(name=ipaddress)                                                                                                                      
      group = Group(name="new-nodes")                                                                                                                  
      group.add_host(host)                                                                                                                             
      inventory = Inventory(host_list=[], vault_password="Hello123")                                                                              
      inventory.add_group(group)                                                                                                                       
      key_file = keyfile                                                                  
      playbook_path = os.path.join(config.ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOKS, playbook)                                                                                 
      pb = PlayBook(                                                                                                                                   
              playbook=playbook_path,                                                                                                                  
              inventory = inventory,                                                                                                                   
              remote_user='deploy',                                                                                                                    
              callbacks=playbook_cb,                                                                                                                   
              runner_callbacks=runner_cb,                                                                                                              
              stats=stats,                                                                                                                             
              private_key_file=key_file                                                                                                                
      )                                                                                                                                                

      results = pb.run()                                                                                                                               
      print results
```

However, `Ansible` [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html) for the `Python API` is very poorly written (doesn't give any detail, except for a simple example). What I needed was to have a similar thing as:

```
ansible-playbook -i hadoop_config -e "namenode_ip=1.2.3.4"
```

That's it, pass the value of `namenode_ip` dynamically to the inventory file using the `Python API`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as adding one or more of these lines to your script after instantiating your group object and before running your playbook:

```
group.set_variable("foo", "BAR")
```